# Vim match with lookaround assertions?

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

In javascript, we can replace all standalone single `i` with `i0`:

```
str = 'if (i < 10 && i1 > 0) { life++; i-- }'
str.replace(/(?<=\W)i(?=\W)/g, 'i0') // => if (i0 < 10 && i1 > 0) { life++; i0-- }
```

How to make this happen in vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, you cannot do that in JavaScript (yet). Look-behind is a very recent feature; apparently only Chrome supports it for now?
2. Your regex is broken anyway: It doesn't match `i` at the beginning or end of a string.
3. The correct regex doesn't require look-ahead/-behind anyway: `/\bi\b/` (`\b` being a word boundary)
4. That was for JavaScript; in vim it's `\<i\>` (`\<` = beginning of word, `\>` = end of word)
5. That said, vim does support look-ahead/-behind: `\W\@<=i\W\@=` (or alternatively `\W\zsi\ze\W`)

Comment: Thanks, but lookhehind is already landed in es2018, see [http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html](http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html)

Comment: Ah, I was looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp. Apparently only Chrome implements it?

Comment: Yes, we need wait a while for full support.